# ERROR: Cannot set priority of secondarynamenode process 84665

Tags: macos, hadoop, namenode, datanode

I recently installed Hadoop on my macbook pro with m1 chip using homebrew. After setting up some necessary configurations, when I tried to `start-dfs.sh` I got this log:

```
╰─ start-dfs.sh                                                                                                      
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
Starting datanodes
Starting secondary namenodes [Huans-MacBook-Pro.local]
MacBook-Pro.local: ERROR: Cannot set priority of secondarynamenode process 84665
2022-03-16 16:05:02,897 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

and my jps shows me no info about the Datanode

```
jps                                                                                                               ─╯
84755 Jps
9418 SecondaryNameNode
81117 NameNode
```

I found out this issue when I tried to do the `hadoop fs -put` command; trying to input a file into a HDFS path and it gave me this error of `put: File /user/hadoop/input/test.txt._COPYING_ could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 0 datanode(s) running and 0 node(s) are excluded in this operation.`

Have anyone encountered and resolved this issue that I have above?